# Merge Videos & Add a Overlay ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-encoding

i am trying to merge intro & outro videos into my main input video and also add a Overlay image in main input video. i wrote this.

```
!ffmpeg -i "$introScreen" -i "$inputVideo" -i "$endScreen" \
-filter_complex "[1:v]overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5[v1]; [0:v][0:a][v1][1:a][2:v][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" "$outputFolder"/"$fileNameUncomp"
```

but this giving me a error...

```
[Parsed_concat_1 @ 0x5651239f8040] Input link in0:v0 parameters (size 640x360, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1920x1080, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_concat_1 @ 0x5651239f8040] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_1
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #2:1
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Need to see **all** log text to provide an answer.

Comment: yeah, i got it.